# Membership info is taken from machine.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5, membership-provider

I started a web application in Visual Studio 2012 wiht the usual login, register, etc. pages. I have SQL database with aspnet_xxx tables. All membership, roles and profiles use my connection string to this database. However, it seems the application uses "Membership" info from machine.config instead of web.config. I am including relevant parts of both below. In the Membership section of web.config, if I leave defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider", and then run login.aspx and try to log in, I get an error saying "invalid object name: dbo.users", if I remove it from Membership section, I don't get the error but Membership section of Machine.config is used. The reason I know this is happening is that I set min password length in web.config to 6 and it is 7 in machine.config. In Register.aspx I have the following line:

```
Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%: Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %> characters in length.
```

and it shows as:

```
Passwords are required to be a minimum of 7 characters in length.
```

I am guessing dbo.users table that shows up in the error message is something in the database that machine.config connection string is referring to.
I have no problem using SSMS and log in as the DB owner of this database (TTUser).

Machine.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<membership>
    <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
            connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
            enablePasswordReset="true" 
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
            applicationName="/" 
            requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
            passwordFormat="Hashed" 
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
            minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
            passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
            passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
    </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
    <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
            connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
            applicationName="/" 
            type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager>
    <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
             connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
             applicationName="/" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
             applicationName="/" 
             type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

we.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="TTConnection"/>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>

    <add name="TTConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Data Source=M3-HP\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=TT_V3;User ID=TT_User;password=abcdef" />

    <add name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Data Source=M3-HP\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=TT_V3;User ID=TT_User;password=abcdef" />
</connectionStrings>

<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
    <providers>
       <add name="DefaultProfileProvider"
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
         connectionStringName="TTConnection" applicationName="/" />
   </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
       <add connectionStringName="TTConnection"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" 
         name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="TTConnection" applicationName="/"
          name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
   </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Any ideas? Spent the whole day and still can't shake it off.

Answer (score 0):

it turned out I was the wrong system.wb version in my web.config. VS added version 4.0.0.0 and I had version 2.0.0.0 in GAC. Changed to 2.0 and the problem went away.